# Why do the new generated synthetic samples improving the performance of the model?

Tags: machine-learning, outliers, model-evaluation, accuracy

I have applied a technique to generate more training data based on the outliers in the dataset. So, I generated more rows that have outliers.

The performance of my classifier (knn) used improved with the new training set that have new outliers than the old ones. Now the question is how does this technique affect the nature of my data to improve the performance of my classifier?

Comment: The performance on *what* dataset?

Comment: the data set has a small number of continuous features. The performance on both data sets, one that have the original training set and the second one which I generated more training set. Any statistical way I could use? how can I know what are the different characteristics of the new training set that makes better prediction than the original training sets?? Why the error rate decreased with the new generated training